# A question about expectation and probability measure in the real situation.

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Define $X_n = 1$ on $[0, 1/n]$ and $0$ otherwise; and probability measure $P_m ([0,1/m])=1 $.

Question: when $m<n$, do we have $E_{P_m} X_n = 1 $.

I know expectation with respect to probability measure, but got stuck in this application.

Comment: What does $P_m(0,1/m)$ mean? Is this the measure of the uniform distribution on $(0,1/m)$?

Comment: @JanoKakara It should be $P_m ([0,1/m])=1 $, $P_m (A)=mP(A) $,where P is the standard probability measure on R.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your probability measure is uniform on $[0,1/m]$, then it is absolutely continuous with respect to the Lebesgue measure on $[0,1]$, and admits a density with respect to this measure in the form
$$ f(t) = \begin{cases} m & \mbox{ if }t\in[0,1/m], \\ 0 & \mbox{ otherwise}. \end{cases}$$
Then the expectation of $X_n$ with respect to $P_m$ can be written as
$$ \mathbf E_{P_m} X_n = \int_\mathbf R X_n(t) \, d P_m(t) = \int_\mathbf R X_n(t) f(t) \,d t = \int_0^{1/m} X_n(t)\, m \, d t.$$
Here, we used first the definition of expectation (integral with respect to a probability measure), then the change of variables (the expression for the density of $P_m$), and finally the fact that $f(t)$ is zero outside $[0,1/m]$. Now, if we continue, we know that $X_n$ is zero outside $[0,1/n]$, but $1/n<1/m$, and
$$ \int_0^{1/m} X_n(t)\, m \, d t = \int_0^{1/n} 1\, m \, d t = m/n, $$
giving us
$$ \mathbf E_{P_m} X_n = m/n \quad \mbox{ for }m<n. $$